# PMF of the Independent Multivariate Bernoulli Distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, independence, bernoulli-distribution, multivariate-distribution

I was reading [this paper](https://pages.stat.wisc.edu/%7Esding/paper/mvb.pdf) on the Multivariate Bernoulli Distribution, which provides the general form of the PMF in equation 3.1. The paper refers to this as the probability distribution function, but they likely meant the probability mass function.

[image]

They also calculate the log-likelihood function.

[image]

I am trying to figure out how the PMF and the log-likelihood function simplify in the case of independence. In particular, I would like to find this simplified PDF parameterized by a vector of probabilities of each element (set of each univariate case probability parameter) rather than every possible interaction between elements.

The paper also provides some theorems on independence of Bernoulli outcomes, particularly Theorem 3.1, but I am having difficulty calculating the PMF in the case of independence using these theorems.

[image]

Comment: How does one have a density function over a discrete set of points? 

Comment: Independence implies the univariate probabilities multiply.

Comment: Hint: you don't need those theorems.  The basic definitions will suffice.

Comment: @whuber Is the pmf simply $f(\bf{k};\bf{p})=\prod_{i=1}^{|\bf{p}|} p_i^{k_i} (1-p_i)^{1-k_i} $?